# About Jmeter with Citrix protocol

Tags: apache, jmeter

I am trying to record script in JMeter through Citrix protocol, able to connect citrix server through JMeter but not able to capture the screenshots. Please help me regarding this

Comment: I'm not familiar with this at all, but have you tried anything yet, any code to show us?

Comment: You can't do this with JMeter. JMeter is suitable for low-level HTTP calls, but not for simulating Citrix (let alone then being able to render the screens).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I cant speak for stability and capability, but people have written [JMeter plugins for ICA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/icafun/) (which is the protocol Citrix uses on the wire) Viva OSS!

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2020, you can use this [new JMeter plugin](https://github.com/blazemeter/CitrixPlugin)

It allows recording, replaying and performance testing Citrix exposed applications.

It can be installed using jmeter-plugins-manager:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=citrix

To see how to install it:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/easily-manage-jmeter-plugins/

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://github.com/blazemeter/CitrixPlugin) will help you.